# Importing shortcuts from CorelDRAW to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw, shortcuts

I'm a user of CorelDRAW since x5. To make some things faster, I'm using Adobe Illustrator with Corel now. 
Since I have a lot of experience with Corel, it becomes usual to do everything with shortcuts (especially alignment).

Is there any way to import, or change Illustrator's shortcuts to match the good ol' Corel?

Answer (score 1):

`Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts`

That encompasses a lot, but not absolutely everything. You'll have to alter them manually.

I don't believe there's a direct method for importing Corel shortcuts to Illustrator. But then I have no idea what format Corel store shortcuts in.

Just personal experience, but it's often better to adapt to the shortcut of an application in the long run. Maintaining a great deal of custom shortcut settings gets to be a bit of (time consuming) trouble with software updates. Eventually, you'll get accustomed to AI shortcuts, even if you struggle a bit at first.